# How to log in the same database from two different PostgreSQL roles using Odoo?

Tags: postgresql, odoo, roles, odoo-10, postgresql-9.5

What I want to do is to login with differents users into the same PostgreSQL database. I need to get this done due to some circunstances that I am not going to describe here (too long).

### First try

I have read [this documentation page about PostgreSQL Roles](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/role-membership.html). So I have created both users and inherit the permissions from one to the another

```sql
CREATE ROLE odoo WITH LOGIN CREATEDB REPLICATION PASSWORD 'odoo' NOINHERIT;
CREATE ROLE odoo_inherit WITH LOGIN CREATEDB REPLICATION PASSWORD 'odoo_inherit' INHERIT;
GRANT odoo TO odoo_inherit;
```

This is the result:

```
    Role name    |                         Attributes       | Member of 
-----------------+------------------------------------------+-----------
 odoo            | No inheritance, Create DB, Replication   | {}
 odoo_inherit    | Create DB, Replication                   | {odoo}
```

### Second try

I have tried faking the [PostgreSQL role](https://www.hagander.net/blog/faking-the-dbo-role-70/), but I cannot login neither from Odoo:

```sql
ALTER USER odoo_inherit SET ROLE odoo;
```

And in fact, when I create a table with the role `odoo_inherit` the new owner of the new table is `odoo`

### Results

The databases owned by the `odoo` role are invisible for the `odoo_inherit` user within Odoo. However I can log in the database with this `psql` command

```
psql -U odoo_inherit -d dbname -W
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Is it a Odoo limitation? Am I missing anything?

**Note:** I have tried that because these are the answers of this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2026655/4891717)

Comment: There is nothing in documentation says that you can do this. You can try to use two instance of Odoo every instance with it's user if that help you. What you need it's not that simple how Odoo will know witch user you need to use what is the condition for that. But i think if you really reallt need that you need to change the framework's code

Comment: @cherif thanks for your attention. Yes, actually I have two instances. One of them with the user `odoo` and the other one with the user `odoo_inherit`. If I log in with `psql`, it works with for both roles. If I log in within Odoo, only the `odoo` role works. I would like to know the reason why is this not working? What login method is Odoo using?

Comment: But what is the error that it give you ?

Comment: @cherif I don´t get any error, simply I don´t see the database in the dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

You can change that in [list_dbs(force=False):](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/odoo/service/db.py#L323), exactly in `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: Did this answer helped you ?